# Scanf Runtime error, have to ctrl-alt-delete

Tags: c, runtime-error, scanf

```
int main()
{

    double a = 1;
    double b = 3; 
    int n = 128;
    int answer = 0;
    printf("select an option(1, 2) ");
    scanf("%d", answer);
    double y = calcIntegral (answer, a, b, n);
    printf("%f \n", y);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it gets to Scanf and then if accepts the answer but stalls completely and I have to force the task to end. What's going on? This is identical to other programs I've written, I think. I tried using %i as well, and using a char instead of a double for the variable "answer". It says it can't access the memory.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &answer)`, the variable answer is an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

Comment: Also, get an OS that works, W2K or later.

Answer (score 2):

For `scanf` with modifier `d`, it matches an optionally signed decimal integer, and the next pointer must be a pointer to int. Says the standard. Also make sure always check `scanf` return value.

```
int ret = scanf("%d", &answer);
if (ret != 1) {
     // failed to input the number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `scanf()`, the variable you read has to be a ***pointer*** . So your statement :

```
scanf("%d", answer);
```

should be :

```
scanf("%d", &answer);
```

as you have declared `answer` to be an `int`, so its memory address is a pointer to an `int`.

---

On the other hand, if you wanted to read a `string` and had declared :

```
char *str;
```

allocating some memory for it, then the statement would be :

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

as `str` is declared as a pointer to `char`.

Comment: In the `char *` example you must make `str` point to some allocated memory before doing the `scanf`; and in the `scanf` you should include a maximum field width to prevent buffer overflow